# Can I get assembly code of an exe file using java?

Tags: java, exe

Hi I need to view code of an `.exe` file which has to be loaded dynamically. So, is there any method of obtaining source code of an exe file in Java or do I need another language to do that?

Comment: Could you please explain the term "monitor assembly code?"

Comment: monitoring in the sense counting the frequency of occurrence of some operations like add,push etc.. in  the assembly code

Comment: I think this has nothing to do with reflection ...

Comment: Do you want to count "frequency of occurrence of some operations" statically (i.e. as they appear in code) or dynamically (i.e. as they being executed)?

Comment: statically as they appear in code

Comment: You could use external disassembler and then work with text file or get source code of open source disassembler and use it  for example https://github.com/wisk/medusa

Answer (score 2):

Standard Java will presumably not be able to do this because what you want to do is platform specific.

I don't know any library that is able to do this.

What you could do is take the exe, extract its code segments and compare their content to a list of opcodes. You could then for example simply iterrate over the bytes and create a list how often hex 0x90 is found, which is an indication for a nop.

Perhaps it is a better solution to simply disassemble the file (into "sourcecode") and count the occurences based on their text representation.